# Validate Linux Config Files

Tags: java, python, bash, shell

I am wondering, if there is any library in any programming language, that could parse Linux config files and validate the contents of config file.

My use-case:

I am trying to get a text file from user and validate the syntax and the contents of that file for user chosen linux config file.

For example:

If user uploaded a file with below content and wants to verify syslog config,

local5.broadcast @256.212.10.12:514

Output should report config file is not correct as syslog doesn't have severity as broadcast and the ip is not valid.

Initially, i am considering, just rsyslog.conf, resolv.conf and ntp.servers config files alone.

Can someone help me out?

Comment: I don't think there is any such generic "magic bullet" program to validate the contents of any arbitrary config file. For one, config files can be in XML, JSON, YAML, CSV, or some other format. Then even if the file syntactically correct, then the data also needs validating.

Comment: Thanks for responding Shane!!!

I knew there's no one solution to handle all config files. I am trying to gather all the separate and config specific library and use it.
So, Let us narrow down to the rsyslog.conf,resolv.conf and ntp.servers files first.
Is there any library that could help validate these files?

Also what do you mean by validating data? It can never be verified because it changes with environment.
For example: dns in my resolv.conf will be different than dns in your resolv.conf

So closest we could verify is syntax.